# Python: Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime

I'm trying to update a date/time value in a MySQL database with Python and I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:
```

The date is initially entered into the database from a Django application and then I'm updating it with a Python script later.

The date is initially crated with the follow code:

```
from django.utils import timezone

last_updated=timezone.now()
```

I'm then trying to update the value with the following code:

```
import datetime

last_updated=datetime.datetime.now()
```

How would I go about resolving this issue so that I can update the last_updated value initially created by Django from a Python script?

Comment: can you update the question with the stack trace ?

Comment: @karthikr There is no stack-trace as it's a warning and not an error. The code continues to run the relevant database field is just not updated as desired.